# How to automatically group tabs in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I am looking for a way to **automatically** create groups of tabs with the same domain. I know that there are extensions to group tabs according to a pre-set pattern but it is a manual action.

When searching for that feature, I stumbled upon many posts from ca. 2020 hinting about the feature to be built-in in Chrome, at that time available via `chrome://flags#tab-groups-auto-create`.

On my Chrome v. 101 there is neither this setting, not I could find one in the usual settings pane.

My questions:

- has that feature been abandoned?

  - if yes: is there an extension that can do the work?
  - if not: where can I enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Currently I have published this extension in chrome store. It does exactly what you need & it does it automatically without click/shortcut keys.

Check here for 1 min youtube demo - [https://youtu.be/SjvnfzsIwuo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SjvnfzsIwuo)

Extension Link - [Chrome Extension store link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/group-tabs-by-domain/icmbnkmjhdapliaologdghjfpcmcimln?hl=en&authuser=0)

Comment: Amazing extension! thank you

Answer (score 0):

This was a favorite feature of mine, which seems to have been removed in Chrome 93 as far as I can tell. I've yet to find a way to restore the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another good option which allows you to add the desired functionality:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/auto-group-tabs/danncghahncanipdoajmakdbeaophenb

Just define URL patterns to meet your needs and leverage "*" to group what is left over.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1173117)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not support auto-grouping of tabs by domain out-of-the-box.

But there are Chrome extensions that provide this functionality.

[Tab Organizer: Productivity Tool](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/group-tabs/hjdhimdmbhgadalmpkkfnpjeppnkfabd) is one of them (I'm the author). This allows to group Chrome tabs by domain or subdomain **automatically** when the "Auto-grouping" option is enabled. It also provides several other features that are useful for managing tabs.